# Is it correct/natural to say "I'm the kind of person **where**..."?

Tags: grammar

I heard a person saying,

> I'm the *kind of person* **where** I don't really share much about my life.

searched the structure of the sentence online and found that there are actually many usages of this expression.

> I'm the kind of *person* **where** I look to myself a lot on how I can get better. What little, nuanced differences can I make?
>
> I've always been the kind of *person* **where** I appreciate tradition, but I feel like individuality is necessary in order to be creative.

It seems a bit strange to see that *a person* and *where* is connected, and I wasn't sure if **where** here is modifying *a person* or not.
Are these sentences grammatically correct? If not, what is the correct/formal alternative for this?

And is it a commonly used/widely understood sentence structure in English colloquially even though it's not grammatical?

Comment: It would be understood but it's not correct. People can be **where** but they are not **where**. They are **who**. Keep **where** for places, situations, circumstances and the like.

Comment: It's not so much the grammar as the idiom that is odd. I would expect to hear _I'm the kind of person who doesn't... the kind of person who looks... the kind of person who appreciates..._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Traditionally, this would be expressed using "who". For example:

> I'm the kind of person who doesn't really share much about my life.

That would clearly be correct.

But usages change and new idioms develop.  If this usage is indeed becoming common, then it can be considerd newly correct.

However [this Google Ngram chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+kind+of+person+where%2Cthe+kind+of+person+who&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20kind%20of%20person%20where%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20kind%20of%20person%20who%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cthe%20kind%20of%20person%20where%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20kind%20of%20person%20who%3B%2Cc0) shows very small use for "the kind of person where", although the use does show as increasing.

Google books does show such uses as:

> - But I think Justine's the kind of person where, if she wants to read a book, she just goes ahead and buys it. [*Where There's a Will* by Elizabeth Spann Craig (2021)]

> - If someone is looking for a patsy, that is the kind of person that they would pick: innocent, isolated, timorous; the kind of person where if you bully them they keep quiet about it; [*Decoded: A Novel* by Mai Jia (2014)]

> - You become the kind of person where I say, we need more practical types like Myla Lewis in the world. [*Clockwork Igni: Action. Adventure. Fantasy. Badassdom* by Christina Bauer (2021)]

> - So me, I'm just the kind of person where I'm always looking for the next. What's the next future? [*Public Enemy: Inside the Terrordome* by Tim Grierson (2015)]

> - But Stephin has always been the kind of person, where, if you ask him what he thinks of the Spinanes record, he's going to tell you. [*Our Noise: The Story of Merge Records, the Indie Label that ...* by John Cook (2009)]

There are  many pages of similar results. Is this enough to call it good current usage? That is a judgement call. I would prefer to stick to "who" in this construction. I don't see any gain in using "where", or anyadditional nuance or clarification. But I am not willing  to say that it is simply wrong, as I once would have. However, I would certainly not use this "where" construction in formal writing, unless I were discussing the usage itself, or quoting those who use it.